# How does this function traverse Binary Tree?

Tags: javascript, iife

I am working on a coding challenge. I found a solution, but I did not understand a part of the solution.

The prompt is

```
Given a binary tree, find the leftmost value in the last row of the tree.

Input:

        1
       / \
      2   3
     /   / \
    4   5   6
       /
      7

Output:
7
```

Tree is defined:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * function TreeNode(val) {
 *     this.val = val;
 *     this.left = this.right = null;
 * }
 */
```

This function works (I did not come up with it):

```
var findBottomLeftValue = function(root) {
    var result = root.val;
    var resultHeight = 0;
    (function recurse (node, height) {
        if (node === null) {
            return;
        }
        if (node.left !== null) {
            recurse(node.left, height + 1);
        }
        if (height > resultHeight) {
            result = node.val;
            resultHeight = height;
        }
        if (node.right !== null) {
            recurse(node.right, height + 1);
        }
    })(root, 1);
    return result;
};
```

I understand most of the line, but frankly, this is my first time seeing IIFE *inside* another function, so maybe that threw me off a little.

What I don't understand is, let's say we start with root 1 (using example above), it starts off with `node` being 1. Since `node.left !== null`, node is now 2, since `node.left !== null`, it goes down to 4. `node.left` is now null, it goes to the next line, which updates `height` and `resultHeight`. Then next line, `node.right` *is* null, and function ends. In my understanding, it **never** went to check nodes `3`, `5`, etc. But the function clearly shows the right answer.

Where on the solution did it check for nodes `3`, `5`, `6`, and `7`?

Comment: "Since `node.left !== null`, node is now `2`", hint: the function call where `node` is 1 is not finished.

Comment: One function does indeed end when it looks (unsuccessfully) for children of `4`, and the function that called that function does end when it checks for a right child of `2`, but the function that called *that* function does ***not*** end when it checks for a right child of `1`.

Comment: What is happening is a core principal of recursive search function, and i wont try to explain it since both zzzzBov & apsillers has already done it. I would however suggest reading up on recursion, one suggestion would be this [free course](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-lesson-205/0/1) on codeacadamy :)

Comment: Gotcha. After reading the answers, especially Regis' answer, I guess I didn't understand how flow works in recursion! Do you guys have any source that corresponds with Regis answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you imagine what is happening as a stack,it's much easier to understand.
It starts on the node with value 1. When it checks the left node,it's left on hold as the first item of the stack(to be called again when it's the topmost item of the stack again)
It would look something like this when it starts on the second iteration:

```
2
---
1
```

Then,it would keep executing and adding to the stack until it check that the node 4 has no left or right node.
At this moment,it would look like this:

```
4
---
2
---
1
```

Then,since there's nothing else to do on the node with value 4,it gets removed out of the stack,and then it executes the next topmost of the stack from where it left off:checking the right node of it.

I hope this helped you visualise and understand what really happens because that really helped me and some college coleagues to understand binary trees.

Comment: This is helpful. I never knew that it works like stacks. Do you have reference/ sources where I can read and learn more to see things this way?

Comment: Sadly,I do not. It was just my personal way of imagining how things happen for me to understand it. Edit: I'm not exactly sure how the language handles it,but I think it's just like stacks,so you could go through that direction to find more information on it.

Answer (score 2):

Your function descents to the left in the first call of `recurse()` (line 9).
If it is done with the left node, it'll go to the right in the second call to `recurse()` (line 16).

The sequence of the nodes will be 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> (2) -> (1) -> 3 -> 5 -> 7 -> (5) -> (3) -> 6 -> (3) -> (1).

The nodes in braces show where the call stack is reduced.